# Add CR & LF in all lines python

Tags: python, python-requests, lf

first of all, thanks to read my post. I hope you guys can help me, I'm really new in Python, sorry maybe the answer is really easy.

I read several posts to add [CR][LN] in all lines but the main issue I have in my script ( I don't create that ), is the need to integrate [CR][LN] in all the lines.

At the moment the script only adds [LN] but not the [CR]. The script goes to SQL to extract some tables, convert the information to CSV ( at this moment the information maintains [CR][LN] ), and after that convert to JSON ( in this step only give me the [LN].

```
import pyodbc
import fileinput
import csv
import pandas as pd
import json
import os
import sys

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=TEST;'
                      'UID=test;'
                      'PWD=12345;'
                      'Database=TEST;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=no;')
cursor = conn.cursor()

query = "SELECT * FROM placeholder"


with open(r"D:\Test.txt") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    print(lines)


for user_input in lines:

    result = query.replace("placeholder", user_input)
    print(result)
    sql_query = pd.read_sql(result,conn)
    df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query)
    user_inputs =  user_input.strip("\n")
    filename = os.path.join('D:\\', user_inputs + '.csv')
    df.to_csv (filename, index = False, encoding='utf-8', sep = '~', quotechar = "`", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    print(filename)
    filename_json = os.path.join('D:\\', user_inputs + '.jsonl')
    csvFilePath = (filename)
    jsonFilePath = (filename_json)
    print(filename_json)
    df_o = df.astype(str)
    df_o = df_o.applymap(lambda x: x.strip() if isinstance(x, str) else x)
    df_o.to_json(filename_json, orient = "records",  lines = bool, date_format = "iso", double_precision = 15, force_ascii = False, date_unit = 'ms', default_handler = str)

dir_name = "D:\\"
test = os.listdir(dir_name)

for item in test:
    if item.endswith(".csv"):
        os.remove(os.path.join(dir_name, item)) 

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

So, I don't know where I need to add this instruction.

Again thanks so much for all you guys always helping me !!!

Kind regards.

Comment: "carriage-return" is Python literal `'\r'`, "line-feed" is the well-known `'\n'`.

Comment: Not sure what `lines=bool` will evaluate to in your call to to_json. You might try `lines=True` and see if that gives what you want.

Comment: Is this only an issue with the CSV being written via `df.to_csv(...)`?

Comment: I try with True, but the results are the same only LN ...

Comment: Can you post a test script that demonstrates the problem that we can run? If there is a point where `\r\n` is maintained but then there is a problem (you say CSV is okay, but JSON is not) then write a test script hardcoding the good stuff and just the code where everything goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @tdelaney, for do that I need to create a new script because as you can see all are concatenated.

The problem is in the line:

df_o.to_json(filename_json, orient = "records",  lines = bool, date_format = "iso", double_precision = 15, force_ascii = False, date_unit = 'ms', default_handler = str)

I think I need use the replace method ???

Comment: Okay, so just guessing, but maybe you are referring to the newlines between records in the json output. You can open the output file yourself, giving it a newline ending, and then you'll get the `\r\n`: `df_o.to_json(open("filename_json", "w", newline="\r\n"), ...)`

Comment: @Carlos - yes, you would need to write a new script, but that's a good thing. A test script that just focuses on your problem that we can run. It shouldn't be very long. I am guessing that you are referring to the newlines between records in the json file. So, sql, csv, etc are not part of the problem.

Comment: To be clear - Is your problem with the newline separators in the JSON file?

Comment: @tdelaney Amazing my friend !!! Really thanks so much !!! You save my life !!! You are a guru !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame.to_json` uses the newline rules of the underlying file object when writing records. If you pass in a file name, `pandas` will open the file in the default "\n" newline mode. Alternately, you could open the file yourself, choosing the newline policy you want.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
df.to_json(open("test.json", "w", newline="\r\n"), orient="records", lines=True)
print(open("test.json", "rb").read())
```

Output

```
b'{"0":1,"1":2,"2":3}\r\n{"0":4,"1":5,"2":6}\r\n{"0":7,"1":8,"2":9}'
```

(Note also that `lines` should be `True` or `False`, not `bool` - which happens to be "truthy" so it works, but not correct).